# Bracket overuse?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I don't know much about the European church system (not that I'm supposed to know anyway, given that I'm from South Asia), but it did come up in a few chapters of our History textbook.

My teacher said this just doesn't sound right to her. I suspect it's probably because I might be using brackets too liberally.

Would it have sounded stilted if I had done something like this instead:

> I don't know much about the European church system, but it did come up in a few chapters of our History textbook. It's not that I'm supposed to know anyway, given that I'm from South Asia.

I understand how brackets popping out in the middle of a long sentence can be confusing/distracting, but at the same time, I also feel it flows nicer with brackets. And it is a more accurate reflection of how my thought process had originally been.

#### EDIT

A bit more context:

> There were only 2/3 paragraphs at best on that topic and from what I've gathered, the Church used to wield more power than any king in Europe (I've no idea how much geographic area it spans). So basically the pope (the head of the Church) ruled over all the kings and could arguably be called the "king of kings".

All of this comes immediately after the sentence in question.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the use of the brackets or the flow of the original sentence.

Comment: The only sour note in your first version is **anyway**.

Comment: What is "2/3 paragraphs"?  Two thirds of a paragraph?  Two or three paragraphs? If the latter, it's **two or three** or **a few**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo It *is* the latter. What is so wrong about using numbers instead of writing them out in words? I get that it has the risk of getting mistaken for a fraction. But I still don't think that it's too confusing as to what I mean. The context should make it apparent.

Comment: `2/3` is not understood to mean "two or three".  The hyphen not the slash is used for that purpose. But when writing, it is conventional to spell out the words of small numbers.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Ah, that's something different. I'd parse `2-3` as "two *to* three", which is basically the same as "two *or* three".

Comment: **two to three** is not idiomatic there in the context of imperfect memory. You're not *estimating*, you're admitting to not remembering exactly. So you'd want to say **two or three**, which is *not* the same as **two to three**.

Comment: Historical comment. In your edit, your characterization of the Pope as the king of kings is excessive. The claims of Popes before Boniface VIII never explicitly went so far as you claim. Their political power outside of Italy was virtually non-existent before the middle of 11th century and was much diminished outside of Italy after the the 13th century. During the approximately intervening 150 years, the Popes' political claims were never fully effective, were frequently contested, and, in a number of cases, resisted militarily. See Investiture Conflict and Avignon Exile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single original sentence is fine... BUT added with the second section there are too many bracket sections.

It is fine if what you are trying to achieve is a stream of consciousness very informal style (think of a good comedian telling a long story with all the little short off shoots).

I personally would concentrate on the following section and leave the first section alone.

> There were only 2/3 paragraphs at best on that topic and from what
>   I've gathered, the Church used to wield more power than any king in
>   Europe (I've no idea how much geographic area it spans). So basically
>   the pope (the head of the Church) ruled over all the kings and could
>   arguably be called the "king of kings".

But from my perspective this is a more stylistic approach than a grammar rule issue.

---

My kids are currently at school learning English as a first language and brackets appear to be out of fashion, they have been taught to use only commas for this purpose.